# Nested exception from dependency in Maven - java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, feign, openfeign

I have a project on Spring Boot 2.3.6, Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR9 with dependency "spring-cloud-starter-openfeign". Also it has jar-dependency "notificli" from internal project.
Here is the **Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>test1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
        <!-- libraries and plugins versions -->
        <build.number>-1</build.number>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>t.tu</groupId>
            <artifactId>notificli</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR9</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse></configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Main class:**

```
package tests.test1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My problem goes from dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>t.tu</groupId>
        <artifactId>notificli</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

It's a jar with:

- Spring Boot 1.5.11.RELEASE
- Spring-cloud-starter-feign 1.3.5.RELEASE

In compile time all is good, but in runtime throws exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [tests.test1.Test1Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at tests.test1.Test1Application.main(Test1Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1090) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1071) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:522) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Couldn't find this class **ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class** because it's need "spring-boot-autoconfigure" dependency from Spring Boot 1.x. In Spring Boot 2.x class not exist.

Ok. If I downgrade spring-boot-autoconfigure like this:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.11.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            ...    
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I have another exceptions:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver

What means I use dependencies from different Spring Boot (1.5 and 2.x)

Ok. Another try. Don't downgrade "spring-boot-autoconfigure", but exclude "spring-cloud-starter-feign" from tricky dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>t.tu</groupId>
        <artifactId>notificli</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0.14</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And than I've got another exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [tests.test1.Test1Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at tests.test1.Test1Application.main(Test1Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1090) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1071) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:522) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could't find **FeignAutoConfiguration.class**, because needed spring-cloud-netflix-core 1.4.4.RELEASE version and below.

If I adding this dependency, I return to exception from beginning of my post: **ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class** not found.

How deal with it?
Thank you for attention.

Comment: You can't mix major versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand... where I mix versions of Spring Boot and Cloud? Could you please give one more comment. Thx!

Comment: Notificli brings in old versions. You mentioned it in the description

Comment: Thank you. 
If we cannot make any changes in Notificli, is there another way how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of